# Dynamically change application properties value In spring Boot Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created a Spring boot Batch project (2.3.0).
I have started the same in a Linux server (Dev environment).
There is an application.properties and application-dev.properties inside the Batch/conf folder.
From application-dev.properties I am taking a value in my Spring Boot Tasklet as below

**Code**

```
@Value("${configurable.json}")
private String configurableJson;
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
configurable.json = {"name":"name1"}
```

Now if I change the configurable.json value in application-dev.properties, the change is not reflected in the batch process even after restarting the batch. When I take a build (my build is a zip) and redeploy it, it is correctly taking. How can I make reflect the changes in property files without a redeployment?

**Command Used to run the Batch**

```
nohup java -cp "/usr/share/Batch/lib:/usr/share/Batch/lib/*:/usr/share/Batch/conf" com.company.batch.Application &
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change properties using property loader. Hope this links helps you [here](https://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jagan. It needs externalize the property file right? So the real application.properties will be in /tmp/example-properties folder under same path where we deployed our app. It needs both the config-service and example-service running parallelly right? In example-service (my case it is a batch not rest service) we need to refer  /tmp/example-properties/application.properties as property file is it?

Comment: Yup. Externalize the file from the jar and create class which will properties aware class which will monitor file change.